# Is it OK to have two lines containing <meta name="keyword"

Tags: html, keyword, meta

I know I am talking unconventional but is it ok to have two lines in an html containing `<meta name="keyword"` lines?  If yes then, are there any side effects of doing that?   If no then why?

Answer (score 0):

You will override the first set of keywords if you do so. If you validate it at http://validator.w3.org/, it is not an error.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.name.html for more infos.

Comment: Their is absolutely no reason to do this tho

Comment: "You will override the first set of keywords if you do so" — the documentation you link to doesn't say what happens (or should happen) if you specify the same piece of data more than once.